# Is it possible to host an ASP.NET Core site on a Mac?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, macos

Background: I downloaded .NET Core & Visual Studio code to my Mac, created a new MVC template project, and ran it. I can access it from my own computer at `localhost:5000`. However another computer on my network cannot access it at `[my ip address]:5000`.

Is there any way at all to host the site on my Mac so other local computers can access?

Comment: I am not sure how it is on Mac, but on windows you have to open port connection before someone can connect using local network.

Comment: On Mac the firewall is off by default. Mine is off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can serve ASP.NET Core web sites from MacOS. I've done so myself.

Your problem is that you're attempting to serve from `localhost` to another computer. `localhost`, the special address `127.0.0.1` (on IPv4) is only meant for **connections within your computer**. You may have seen other software that acts differently, but if you've configured a server to use `localhost`, it's expected that no other machine will be able to connect to it.

If you want to accept connections from any address, use the special address `0.0.0.0` instead. This tells the software to accept connections on any address/network interface that it can see.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried this using the ".UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")" method on the WebHostbuilder. Still not working though. Any other ideas?

Comment: @DSN_SLO I'm not sure what else to suggest beyond general troubleshooting, like: are you sure the computer are on the same network and can see each other? Can you run a different type of test server and confirm that it works?

Comment: It's working! I think it was just a network problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I feel inspired to say that this is a particularity of development webservers. A webserver normally doesn't care where requests are coming from. It listens on a port on a machine. How the request finds the machine is none of it's business.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to do the same with MVC Core App.

In the `Properties/launchSettings.json` in the Solutions Name Property:

```
  "applicationUrl": "http://your_ip:5000",
```